# TypeError: Cannot read property 'AccountToken' of undefined

Tags: jestjs, onchange

Trying to run the following test for a select component that is being import  'react-select'
I have the click events running fine, but onChange event is displaying an error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Accounts' of undefined
```

Here is where the error is located, line :

```
   setReport = () => {
let data = this.state.Account.accountBody;

this.setState({
  AccountToken: data.AccountToken,
```

Render();

```
<Select
  className={'field-input-select margin-right'}
  id='accounts-id-test'
  value={this.state.Account}
  onChange={(e) => { this.setState({Account: e}, ()=>{this.setReport()}) }}
```

Using mount :

```
it("should check button click event - Select ", () => {
 baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
wrapper.find('CLASS YOUR TESTING').setState({
    contactOptions:[],
    Account:[[""]],
    accountOptions: [{ value: 'test', label: 'label test', accountBody: "test account" }],
    showRequired: false,
    loading:false
});
wrapper.update() 


// wrapper.update() 
 wrapper.find('CLASS YOUR TESTING').find('Select').at(0).props().onChange({
    contactBody:{
        Accounts:[]
 }})
```

onChange works at(0) and not at (1) . Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that:

```
let contactBody = contact.contactBody;
```

is `undefined` so now you should try to debug with `console.log` or other ways and see why it is `undefined` and find a Solution

Comment: console.log(wrapper.debug()) not sure where to look at it to be hoenst. I did a console.log(wrapper state) and all i see is null

Comment: try `console.log(contact)` in the function

Comment: I place it right after  let contactBody = contact.contactBody; and its showing contactid-test.

Comment: So I decided to place after   let accountOptions = contactBody.Accounts.map and its not there anymroe

Comment: at node 0 the test pass and works fine. But not at node 1 -  i

Comment: Plasma , i posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Able to figure out

```
   wrapper.find('CLASS YOUR TESTING').find('Select').at(1).props().onChange({
    accountBody:{
        LOA:{ 
             Documents:{
                 Signers:[],
             }
            }
         }
    })
```